# Activate webfeatures on all SharePoint online webs

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online, office-365, feature-activation

I want to activate a webfeature on all subsites of a sitecollection in Office 365 / SharePoint online.

I thought i can do the actions in a SiteCollection Feature, but that's throwing a timeout error. So I create a webfeature. But how can i enable it on al sites?

Is there an Powershell Example, or another solution?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there are no PowerShell script for feature activation, on a SPO-site. The only available script are listed in the technet article [Index of Windows PowerShell for SharePoint Online cmdlets](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161364.aspx).

Instead you need to activate the feature on each subsite, but if you have a list of the subsite URL:s it's fairly quick if you copy-paste the URL below after the subsite url:

```
https://my-spo-root-url/subsite-url/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/_layouts/15/ManageFeatures.aspx
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be a bit late now but you can use a the SharePoint Online Automation cmdlets https://sharepointonlineautomationcmdlets.codeplex.com/ to do this. Just write a function which uses Get-SPOSubWebs and runs through all of the subsites recursively and use the Install-SPOWebFeature cmdlet to activate the features.

Something like

```
$ctx = Get-SPOContext url username password
Install-SPOWebFeature -Web $ctx.Web -FeatureId {some id}

Get-SPOSubWebs -Web $ctx.Web | ForEach-Object {
   Install-SPOWebFeature -Web $_ -FeatureId {some id}
}
```

Would do the first level.